# Bootstrap modal does not show up on clicking button

Tags: html

i have a delete button on my table column  by clicking that button i want to display a bootstrap modal for confirm message but its deleting the data but not displaying the modal.please help

my modal

```
<!-- modal  confirm message -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Enter Delatils</h4>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="message-box"></div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure?
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="btn-yes" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
    </div>
  <!-- /modal confirm message-->
```

and here is my Javascript

```
$(document).on('click','#btn_delete',function(){
var id = $(this).data('id7');
$('#modal-confirm').modal({show:true});
$('document').on('click','#btn-yes', function(){
    $.ajax({
    url:'include/delete-client-class.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{'id':id},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }

}); 
});
```

});

Comment: Have you included the reference to the bootstrap js file?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you *might* not have included the reference to the bootstrap js file, or that the version of jquery is higher than that of bootstrap.

For the example to work properly, you need to reference the bootstrap css:

```
<link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

... and in the body, after the jquery's file reference, you need to reference bootstrap's js file:

```
<script data-require="jquery@1.9.1" data-semver="1.9.1" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Please, refer to this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9nJ0Za2o1TPVee4MSxO6?p=preview) example where I tried to simulate the modal by using parts of your code.